# F# creating a hand with playing cards

Tags: f#

I have this code that generates a deck of cards and a function that can randomly choose one of the 52 cards, however. I now need a way to give a play five unique cards that are from the deck and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Try shuffling the deck and taking 5 from the top

Comment: how would i do a shuffle and take from the top?

Comment: Well there are lots of ways to shuffle a deck, but the easiest being take a card at random, put it into a new deck, and repeat until the original deck is empty. You could tweak your `GetCard` to remove the card it selected, then repeat that 52 times. Pick the first 5 cards with `Seq.take 5`.

Comment: Do you think you could write out what you mean for me in code? i  am very new to F# and don't get how to do it? sorry

Comment: Incidentally, if you don't mind using reflection you can generate `allSuits` and `allFaces` directly from their respective DUs: e.g. ```let allFaces = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<Faces> |> List.ofSeq```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, one way to create this hand is to shuffle a deck then take 5 cards from the top.

```
type Suit = Diamonds | Hearts | Clubs | Spades
 
type Face =
    | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
    | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
 
type Card = { Face: Face; Suit : Suit }

let allFaces = [
   Two; Three; Four; Five; Six; Seven; Eight; Nine; Ten;
   Jack; Queen; King; Ace
]

let allSuits = [ Diamonds; Hearts; Clubs; Spades ]

let fullDeck = [
    for suit in allSuits do
        for face in allFaces do
             yield { Face = face; Suit = suit } 
]

// returns a random card and the remaining deck
let GetCard (deck: Card list) =
    let rand = new System.Random()
    let idx = rand.Next(deck.Length)
    let card = deck.[idx]
    (card, List.except [card] deck)

// shuffle a deck
let rec shuffle = function
    | card :: [] -> [card]
    | deck -> let (card, rest) = GetCard deck
              card :: shuffle rest

let hand deck = deck |> shuffle |> List.take 5

fullDeck |> hand |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Thank You very much, Is there a way to remove the brackets and stuff on output?

Comment: Not that I know of, but there may be some modifiers available for the `A` specifier. I'm pretty new to F# also but I've use Haskell in the past

Comment: You can create a function to print the list of Cards, just iterate over the list with `List.iter` and print every card.

Comment: @AMieres How would you do this? Would this remove the brackets from the output?

Comment: @TESTING1 AMieres is saying to create your own print function that prints a single card, and apply that over the whole list. You can make it print however you want. For example, `let printCard (card: Card) = printfn "%O of %O" card.Face card.Suit` then apply over the hand with `fullDeck |> hand |> List.iter printCard`

Comment: FYI the `%A` in  ```printfn "%A"``` is a generic pretty printer for any type, hence the brackets, in this case, since you are printing a list. You want something more custom use @brady-dean 's comment just above.

Comment: what does the %O stand for?

Comment: What would i do if i wanted to allow the user to swap up to three cards, with the three cards they specify, of course, the new cards would be random and they would not get the same cards again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `%O` is the format specifier for objects, it calls `ToString` on the object to get a string representation. To solve your second problem, I would first parametrize `hand` with the number of cards to draw, eg `let hand n deck = deck |> shuffle |> List.take n`. Then, after the user specifies 3 cards, you can remove them from their hand with `List.except`. Then, draw 3 cards from the remaining deck with `hand 3`, and add them to the player's hand with `List.append`.

Comment: How would this work, like if i had a function, where they say YES or no to swapping. If yes pass the player's hand to a new function and then remove and append, how would i do that? Whenever i try with List.Except it says it will be ignored?

Comment: @TESTING1 start a new question with all the details